# I am building a chatbot and I need corpora

Tags: corpora, resource-request

I am building a chatbot and I need corpora to train them. I need corpora that is used as general chatting. I would be happy if anyone would help me with it.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What language? What shall the bot chat about?

Comment: Isn't this a better fit for something like Stack Overflow?

Comment: @jknappen I am trying it for entertainment and language I am using is English

Comment: @PElliott this is linguistics question I guess

Comment: @BishalGautam I'm not sure I agree. Linguistics is the scientific study of language. This is asking for corpora to help build a chatbot. I don't see the link.

Comment: @PElliott: I think it is okay to ask for language resources like corpora here no matter for what purpose the resource is used later on.

Comment: Whether it's on-topic or not, it's far too broad and unspecific.

Answer (score 2):

Project Gutenberg has some of the largest free open-source corpora available (in multiple languages).  You can download as much or as little as you wish in a variety of formats.  A clever chatbot can quote back lines from Shakespeare or Dickens perhaps.  http://www.gutenberg.org/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dataset of IRC chats: http://chatlogs.planetrdf.com/swig/. This is probably what you need.

Comment: Can I get pure corpora, not with the names. That would certainly help.